# url mapping only ip_address and port in servlet no application name in URL

Tags: java, servlets

Hiii all,

Am very new to this J2EE. I have to access the servlet URL as "localhost:8080"

my web.xml file is follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
       xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
       http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
       id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">



<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
   <servlet>
   <servlet-name>Ticky taka</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>servlets.TestServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Ticky taka</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

The problem is if i want to access the Servlet i have to give the `10.10.10.114:8080/TickyTacka/` URL. instead of the above URl i wish to make it as

```
10.10.10.114:8080
```

Is it possible

I am using Apache tomcat 7

Please advice

Thank you

Comment: You can't do this using web.xml since `TickyTacka` is the application name needed for reference in request.

Comment: @vbera Thank you for your reply, Is there any other way to do this :)

Comment: That's depend on which server you are using. In apache, you can do it via config file. Check this http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/apache-2-basic-configuration-on-unix-like-systems--net-26607

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tomcat has the notion of application context path, wich externally is the name of the application, in your case `TickyTacka`, and internally the path where the application is installed under tomcap `webapps` directory.

There is a special case `ROOT` application context. Internally it is the directory `webapps/ROOT`, but it is mapped to an empty application context path. So if you deploy your web application to `ROOT` it will be accessible at `http://10.10.10.114:8080/`.

But it is a kind of special application context and I know its usage is not recommended. As vbera said, it is more common to deploy application in normal application context paths, and *hide* those paths behind URL rewriting through `apache` or `nginx`.

Comment: Thank you: I have deleted the root folder and renamed the ticky tacka to ROOT :)